# Putting the same key to all element of an array

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I get an array using the function preg_match_all. The code is as it is:

```
 $str = $dataGroups['groups'];
 preg_match_all('/[0-9]/', $str, $matches);
```

It return an associated array from the type:

```
array(5) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" [2]=> string(1) "3" [3]=> string(1) "4" [4]=> string(1) "5" }
```

Where the values are actually id's for a Link table, where I have two foreign keys, the values of the one FK are the values of the array above, what I need is to assign the keys with another value which should be the same for all elements because I\m gonna use it for multiple inserts in the table.So to make it clear If I want to insert all values which have id 67 I think I need something like this form my codeigniter active record:

> array(5) { [67]=> string(1) "1" [67]=> string(1) "2" [67]=> string(1) "3" [67]=> string(1) "4" [67]=> string(1) "5" }

And use the AR command:

> $this->db->insert('mytable', $matches[0]);

I'm gonna try it for first time so any advice is appreciated, but the most important is to change the value of the keys with the same number, and maybe if you could tell if this is the right way to do the multiple insert using CodeIgniter AR.
Thanks

Leron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have duplicate keys in an array, they have to be unique as they are there for referencing!

However, what you could do it have an associative array like so:

```
$array = array(
    1 => array(
        'id' => 67
    ),
    2 => array(
        'id' => 67
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

eh, how would that work? you cannot have multiple identical array keys; what you could do is to have an array storing all strings under the same key, e.g.

```
array(
    "67" => array(
        "string 1",
        "string 2",
        ...
        "string 5"
    )
);
```

and I'm not sure how that would work for your database ... this whole thing smell like poor database/table design - i.e. you clearly cannot use '67' as the primary key, and so then you shouldn't be adding rows based on its value, but rather using a unique key (e.g. auto-incremented column)